# fr units cannot be the minimin value of minmax() (css)

Tags: css, css-grid

When I tried putting 1fr in the first slot of `minmax()`and the browser dev tools tells me that it is not valid.
The moment I take away the 1fr, it works.

Code that did not work:

```
.grid {
  grid-template-rows: minmax(1fr, auto); /* this did not work */
}
```

Is there any work arounds to this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this grid ? :)

Comment: @CharlesLavalard I wanted to make a calculator. And the `minmax()` is for the number display. I want the display to be 1.2fr by default and resize when the number gets long and wraps.

Comment: I edited my answer so you can see how it works :)

Comment: @CharlesLavalard But I just realized, it might not work with my screen. What I have is a `div` (which is a grid item) for my screen, and there are two `div`s inside the `div`. One of them is for the previous operand, one of them is for the current operand. But users can type in very long numbers, so I want to wrap them. That means the content sizes of the grid item will change. So I want it to be 1.2fr when it is empty, but resize according to the content. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can make another question with a snippet.
I don't quite understand the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1fr` cannot be your minimum because 1fr takes

> 1 fraction of the leftover space in the grid container

[Here is the doc](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#fr-unit)

You can do something like this

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat( auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.bloc {
display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="bloc">1</div>
  <div class="bloc">2</div>
  <div class="bloc">3</div>
  <div class="bloc">4</div>
  <div class="bloc">5</div>
  <div class="bloc">6</div>
  <div class="bloc">7</div>
  <div class="bloc">8</div>
  <div class="bloc">9</div>
</div>
```